# Correct way to transition between views so that navigation / tab bar animate nicely

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

Through-out my app, I have different colored navigation bars. 
Also, I have some graphs which are shown in landscape, whereas the rest of my app in in portrait.
And on some views, I hide my tab bar.

I change the navigation bar color in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear.

My problem is that the transition effect between views looks odd. 
Where the navigation bar has a different colour, the color changes too quickly and the first screen changes. Or you can see the tab bar being removed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is some typical code which I use.

```
CBViewController *nextController = [[CBViewController alloc] 
      initWithNibName:@"CBView" bundle:nil];
nextController.title = @"CB";   
nextController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

I'm not looking for none standard effect, but something which doesn't look odd.

Although, I have seen a sliding effect, from the first view to the second which looks good.

Comment: We can't ell what you're doing wrong, because we don't know what you want. It would help if you would describe what kind of animation you would like to see.

Comment: @rdelmar looking at iTunes, where it changes the nav bar colour from dark to light, reckon it just needs to be faster.

Answer (score -1):

After your comment, I'm still not sure what you're looking for -- I don't see any navigation bar color change in my iTunes (they update iTunes so often, maybe we're looking at different versions). Anyway, the following code will cause the navigation bar to change color as it transitions to a new controller. Since the push animation is only about 0.3 seconds, and NSTimer is limited to about 0.05 seconds resolution, I did six steps in going from one color to the next (from green to yellow).

```
-(IBAction)pushWithColorChange:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *nextController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Yellow"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(changeColor:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)changeColor:(NSTimer *) timer {
    static float i=0.03;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:.34 - i saturation:.5 brightness:.7 alpha:1];
    i += 0.03;
    if (i > .18) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: @rdlmar Interesting, I wasn't aware that the transition effect was limited to the view. But obviously when you look at transition animation code, sure enough it's just altering the view. I take it can't call perhaps a fade transition on the navigation bar ?

Comment: @Jules, what kind of fade? Do you want to fade out the bar completely? You can animate the alpha value of the navigation bar (just like any other UIView subclass).

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what will look good / work. At the moment to tint colour is used by buttons which keep the colour until the end of the push or pop animation. However the tint changes at the start of the animation. I think a swipe slide effect for both view and bar would look good. I'm just concerned it will look odd. Thanks so far.

Comment: @rdlemar, I know what look amazing, if the bars looked separate. E.g.     AAA button AA title AAAAABBB button BB title BBBBB